# How to pass parent field in sub union query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this query and its giving an error that unknown U.UserID column in where clause but I can't see any error in it as my Users table instance is U

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(U.UserID),
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT(UserID))
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  FriendID as UserID
                        FROM    Friends
                        WHERE   UserID=U.UserID AND Status=1
                        UNION All
                        SELECT  UserID
                        FROM    Follow
                        WHERE   Type='user' AND TypeEntityID=U.UserID
                    ) tbl
        ) as NoOfFriendsFollow
FROM    `Users` `U`
WHERE   `U`.`UserID` IN('1')
LIMIT   10
```

Any solution for this query or let me know where I'm wrong

Comment: thanks @Stefano for edit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(UserID), 
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(UserID)) FROM 
    (
        SELECT FriendID as UserID FROM Friends F
        INNER JOIN Users U ON U.UserID=F.FriendID
        WHERE F.Status=1 
        UNION All 
        SELECT FF.UserID FROM Follow FF
        INNER JOIN Users U ON U.UserID=FF.UserID
        WHERE Type='user' AND TypeEntityID=U.UserID 
    ) tbl
) as NoOfFriendsFollow 
FROM Users WHERE UserID IN('1') LIMIT 10;
```

Just try above code.
Hope this will helps.

Comment: it returns same no of followers for any input

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySSQL does not permit you to use an outer table reference "two levels down".  So you can do:

```
SELECT U.UserID,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)
        FROM (SELECT fr.FriendID as UserID, fr.FriendId as compareId
              FROM Friends fr
              WHERE fr.Status = 1
              UNION All
              SELECT f.UserID, f.TypeEntityID as compareId
              FROM Follow f
              WHERE f.Type = 'user'
             ) tbl
         WHERE tbl.UserID = compareId
        ) as NoOfFriendsFollow
FROM Users U
WHERE U.UserID IN (1)
LIMIT 10;
```

Notes:

- This moves the comparison into the middle subquery, so the query parses.
- Presumably `UserId` is an integer.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- The `GROUP_CONCAT()` doesn't make sense.  It turns the query into an aggregation query that returns only one row.
- I double the `LIMIT` is needed either. There should be one row per `UserId`.
- Always use qualified column names when you have multiple tables in a query.

Comment: @SagarGangwal . . . That should be just `compareId`, not `compareId.UserId`.